# AngularJS order by not working with html value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, sorting

I have a problem regarding angularjs orderby when the field is html value.

Here is my Code:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="data in competencyReport | orderBy:sortOrder:reverse">
  <td style="border-right:none"><span data-ng-bind-html="data.competencyDescription |rawHtml"></span></td>
  <td style="border-right:none;border-left:none;width:100px">{{data.grade}}</td>
  <td style="border-right:none;border-left:none;width:100px">{{data.averageScore}}</td>
  <td style="border-right:none;border-left:none;width:30px">{{data.percentage.toFixed(2)}}</td>
  <td style="border-left:none;width:200px">
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{data.percentage.toFixed(2)}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" data-ng-style="showProgress(data.percentage)">
            <span class="sr-only">{{data.percentage.toFixed(2)}} % Complete (success)</span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

This is the problem

```
<td style="border-right:none"><span data-ng-bind-html="data.competencyDescription |rawHtml"></span></td>
```

`data.competencyDescription` is a HTML value

All other field can be sort ascending and descending but only `competencyDescription` field is not.

Why is it happened and how to sort this one ascending and descending?

Comment: first you write `competencyDescription` and then you write `compe**N**tencyDescription ` Are you sure you didn't make a spelling-error in your code?

Comment: im sorry for that..i use competencyDescription

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, change the line to match the others.

```
<td style="border-right:none">{{renderHtml(data.competencyDescription)}}</td>
```

Then to ensure the HTML is rendered, add something like this to your controller:

```
$scope.renderHtml = function(html_code)
{
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
};
```

Don't forget to add $sce to the top of the controller next to $scope, etc...

Comment: actually i got a filter like that.. `data-ng-bind-html="data.competencyDescription |rawHtml"` the raw html is a filter like that.. my problem how to orderby that html like this `orderBy:sortOrder:reverse`

Comment: "Don't forget to add $sce to the top of the controller next to $scope, etc..." also called "dependency injection" ;)